# Am I missing something in ampere’s law ? Field due to infinite wire same as that due to a finite wire?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

On solving via biot savarts equation we get the values of magnetic  field :
$$\overrightarrow{d B}=\frac{u_0}{4 \pi} i \frac{\overrightarrow{d l} \times \vec{r}}{r^3} $$
[image: original image]
For Finite wire : $$\vec{B}=\frac{u_0}{4 \pi r} i(\sin \alpha+\sin \beta)$$
Where alpha and beta are angles substended by the rod at a point P distance $r$ from the finite rod.
When the rod length $\rightarrow \infty$
$$\begin{aligned} & \alpha \rightarrow 90^{\circ} \\ & \beta \rightarrow 90^{\circ}\end{aligned} $$

That is   $\frac{u_0}{2 \pi r} i$
$$
\oint \vec{B} \cdot \overrightarrow{d l}=u_0 i_{\text {enclosed }}
$$
Using ampere’s law When we solve for magnetic field due to a infinite current carrying wire at a distance $r$ We get the same value as that as that due to a finite wire . That is   $$\frac{u_0}{2 \pi r} i$$

Comment: You say "On solving via Biot-Savarts equation we get different value of the field". Can you explain exactly exactly why you think this ?

Comment: Note that you cannot apply Biot-Savart to "a finite wire"... nor can you apply any equation to find the magnetic field of an unphysical situation. (a finite wire cannot conduct electricity, only a closed loop can). When you try to apply Biot-Savart to a finite wire you get something that isn't curl free outside of the wire. This may be part of the problem. If you want a finite wire, and you account for the fact that charge is building up on both ends, you can find the electric and magnetic field with Jefimenko's equations https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jefimenko%27s_equations

Comment: But also Ampere's law doesn't tell you everything about the magnetic field. It only tells you the total component along the loop. The two versions can still differ by the components perpendicular to the loop. Without more work shown I can't say which of these two problems you're experiencing

Comment: I have edited so that it sounds more clear .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A finite wire carrying a current needs to source and sink the current from somewhere so a complete circuit might look like this.

[image]

The right hand side of your equation $\oint \vec{B} \cdot \overrightarrow{d l}=\mu_0 i_{\text {enclosed }}$ is fine but for the left hand side you have  $\oint (\vec B + \vec {B_1}+\vec {B_2}+\vec {B_3})\cdot \vec {dl}$ not just $\oint \vec B \cdot \vec {dl}$

Comment: But the finite wire is only part under observation we must define the field  due to very part under observation and not the other elements

Comment: Finally got the answer thanks sir